# Value of textarea? how to fill one?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to fill a `textarea` using javascript, the thing is i found out that `textarea` doesn't have the value tag, and `<textarea ..></textarea>` is not an option since i cant use it with javascript.

Edit :

```
content.document.getElementsByName("cr-work-desc0").innerHTML = "125645";
content.document.getElementsByName("cr-work-urls0").textContent = "this is some sample text";
content.document.getElementsByName("infringing-urls0")[0].setAttribute("value","testing to");
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have the value tag? Are you trying to set a textarea's value with JavaScript? If so, just use `document.getElementById("textarea_id").value = "Whatever";`

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No i am not using jquery
and **lan** yes that is what i mean but i get nothing even when doing the way you said

Comment: Please post your JS so we can diagnose... are you getting errors anywhere else?

Comment: No i am not getting any errors, I used the 3 methods above but none seems to work

Comment: and none of them is the same as the code suggested by Ian and jterry

Comment: I don't know what `content` is, but the result of `.getElementsByName()` is a collection, so you **have** to index it to get a certain element. Try `content.document.getElementsByName("whatever_name")[0].value = "TESTING";`. The `[0]` is required

Comment: if you are using jquery and classes, you must set it like `$('.selector')[0].value = 'value'` if you use `val()` it does not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just set the value of the field via `document.getElementById('thefield').value = 'value'`.

Comment: That is what i am trying but it doesn't work, when i check the html code, i can see that the tag value has the text i want, but only on the source code, the actual textarea is empty.

Comment: My bad, i didnt do it exactly like you said, it is working, thank youuu

Answer (score 3):

Try following code

```js
document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML="Blah Blah";
```

```html
<textarea id="aa"></textarea>
```

Both innerHTML and value works fine.

You can write anything in place of aaaa

Answer (score 2):

For an `input` element, the **default value** is specified by the `value` *attribute* and the **current value** is specified by the `value` *property*.

A `textarea` is different. The **default value** is specified by the text node that is a child of the element.

i.e.:

```
<textarea>this is the default value</textarea>
```

However the **current value** is still specified by the `value` *property*.

```
document.getElementById('thefield').value = 'value';
```

… even though there is no `value` *attribute* for textarea elements.

---

You can modify the default value (`input.setAttribute("value", "new value")` or `textarea.innerHTML = "new value"`) which will:

- Modify the displayed value providing it hasn't changed (e.g. by the user typing in it)
- Modify the value that the control will be reset to if a *reset* button is activated

… but usually, you will want to change (and read) the *current value* which will always be `input.value` / `textarea.value`.