# I need to create a button, which when clicked, auto fills the notes section of a form

Tags: javascript, button, autofill

I'm by no means an expert at javascript, so any help would be much appreciated. Like the title suggests, I want to create a button, which when clicked, will autofill the notes section of a form with the following information; "about employee discount."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048666/value-of-textarea-how-to-fill-one

Comment: Are there any code you wrote? If there are, plase edit the question and paste it here.

Comment: HTML-
<a href="/contactus" class="redbutton uc small" rel="nofollow" role="button" id="btn" onClick="autofill">Now Offering Employee Discount Rates</a>

JS-

Comment: <script>
       $('#btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#txtNotes').text('About employee discount inquiry.');
});
    </script>

Comment: thanks everyone - i got it to work.

Comment: if you have found the solution, then lets close this question. tick the solution which solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click handler for your button and update the value/content of label/textarea/div/span.

The below solution is a `jQuery` solution, if your not aware of what is `jQuery`, then check [this video](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/javascript-jquery-dom/).

Before running below script load the jquery library from cdn into your page (paste this script inside `head` tag)

`<script type="type/script" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

**HTML CODE:**

```
<input type="button" value="process" id="btn"/>
<span id="notes"></span>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').on('click',function(){
     $('#notes').text('about employee discount.'); //assuming #notes is a span tag.
  });
});
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged in this question. If you want to offer a jQuery solution I would recommend you Clearly explain the use of jQuery and show how to link to the jQuery library. It might not be tagged due to many reasons.

Comment: @NewToJS; didnt see the `tags` section, anyway i have added the required info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="auto fill" onclick="autofill('about employee discount.')" />

<input type="text" id="output1" />
<p id="output2"></p>
```

and here is your javascript:

```
var output1 = document.getElementById("output1");
var output2 = document.getElementById("output2");

var autofill = function(text) {
    output1.value = text;
    output2.innerHTML = text;
}
```

in some element like *p* and *span* you must use **innerHTML** to get or set values and in some element like *input* use must use **value**.

https://jsbin.com/namuci/edit?html,js,output